# Async Call On Application Start Returning Null

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I have a call that retrieves all of the categories in a database when you navigate to the main page. The idea is that the index page shows a list of categories dynamically. The categories were placed by using EF .Net Core to scaffold the code that inserts the categories into the database - here's what that db looks like.

https://gyazo.com/c407f03ae60a82c6fa6f9ee12105089d

EDIT: Get Categories:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<List<Category>> GetCategoriesFromDb()
        {
            return await _context.Categories.Where(x => x.ParentId == 0).ToListAsync();
        }
```

It throws this error:

https://gyazo.com/7e27dda9ff57b6e28b58b563abd05767

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
AspNetCore.Views_Home__categories.ExecuteAsync() in _categories.cshtml
+
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage 
page, ViewContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, 
ViewContext context, bool invokeViewStarts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context) = 
AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
+
<partial name="_categories" , for="Categories" />
```

It appears that upon subsequent navigation to the page (literally refresh it once) the error goes away.

Here's the controller where it's failing:

https://gyazo.com/ee6db603cde49a7b704b200e7e5fa2dc

```
// Model stores an IEnumerable of Products and Categories to be used with the two partial views.
            Index myModel = new Index();
            myModel.Categories = new List<Category>();
            myModel.Products = new List<Product>();

            myModel.Categories = await GetCategories();
```

Here's the code and View in question:

https://gyazo.com/634b6867601fc582836e284cdacb0ca3

```
@{
@model List<Category>
}


<div>

    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="~/Home/Index/" style="margin-bottom:10px;">All</a>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {

            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="~/Home/Index?Category=@item.Name&Zip=@ViewBag.Zip" style="margin-bottom:10px;">@item.Name</a>
        }


    }
    else
    {
        <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="~/Home/Index/" style="margin-bottom:10px;">All</a>
    }
</div>
```

Here's the View Model:

https://gyazo.com/e5053f6827d2198742279eb37071c733

```
namespace Market.Views.Home
{
public class Index
{

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

If I navigate to the page again, the error goes away.
I'm afraid that this is responsible for the .4% times my application returns a 500 error.

I've tried changing it from an IEnumerable to a List - but I don't actually know how to troubleshoot the problem. It seems like I need to handle when the list of categories is null, but I'd prefer the view to not crash at all and to wait until all the categories are retrieved.

I can tell it's because the list of categories is null when the Razor view hits the if statement checking to see if there are categories. It should simply re-try until there are categories, I think, but I'm not sure.

EDIT:
Upon further inspection, the error is happening on my SQL db server according to Azure. It comes with this exception which appears to be related to the problem I'm having locally.

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.GetGeoProducts(Nullable`1 Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String Category) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 162
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String Category, Double Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String sortOrder, String currentFilter, Nullable`1 pageNumber) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 80
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextResourceFilter()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Don't post error messages and code as images, nobody wants to see those.

Comment: You didn't post the code for the most important part: `GetCategories`.

Comment: Sorry for the errors - I solved it and updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys - this ended up being a critical lesson in logging.

I changed the code to get categories to just create a pre-populated SelectList instead of retrieving it from the DB.

```
@{
var Categories = new List<Category>(){
            //new Category
            //{
            //    CategoryId = 1,
            //    ParentId = 0,
            //    Name = "All",
            //    ParentCategory = null
            //},
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 2,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Electronics",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 3,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Furniture",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 4,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Clothing",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 5,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Shoes",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 6,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Video Games",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 7,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Books",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 8,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Tools",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 9,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Vehicles",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 10,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Free",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 11,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Jewelry",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 12,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Crafts",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 13,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Crafts",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 14,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Appliances",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 15,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Health",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 16,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Tickets",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 17,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Services",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 18,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Home & Garden",
                ParentCategory = null
            },
            new Category
            {
                CategoryId = 19,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Collectibles",
                ParentCategory = null
            }
};
```

But the error was still being thrown - so I checked the logs after adding NLog:

```
    2019-05-06 12:09:56.6564|ERROR|Market.Controllers.HomeController|MaxMind.GeoIP2.Exceptions.AddressNotFoundException: The address ::1 is not in the database.
   at MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader.Execute[T](String ipStr, IPAddress ipAddress, String type, Boolean throwOnNullResponse)
   at MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader.City(IPAddress ipAddress)
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.GetGeoProducts(Nullable`1 Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String Category) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 169
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String Category, Nullable`1 Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String sortOrder, String currentFilter, Nullable`1 pageNumber) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 85
2019-05-06 12:12:07.8714|ERROR|Market.Controllers.HomeController|MaxMind.GeoIP2.Exceptions.AddressNotFoundException: The address ::1 is not in the database.
   at MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader.Execute[T](String ipStr, IPAddress ipAddress, String type, Boolean throwOnNullResponse)
   at MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader.City(IPAddress ipAddress)
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.GetGeoProducts(Nullable`1 Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String Category) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 169
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String Category, Nullable`1 Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String sortOrder, String currentFilter, Nullable`1 pageNumber) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 85
2019-05-06 12:21:50.0824|ERROR|Market.Controllers.HomeController|MaxMind.GeoIP2.Exceptions.AddressNotFoundException: The address ::1 is not in the database.
   at MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader.Execute[T](String ipStr, IPAddress ipAddress, String type, Boolean throwOnNullResponse)
   at MaxMind.GeoIP2.DatabaseReader.City(IPAddress ipAddress)
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.GetGeoProducts(Nullable`1 Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String Category) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 169
   at Market.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String Category, Nullable`1 Distance, String productSearch, String Zip, String sortOrder, String currentFilter, Nullable`1 pageNumber) in C:\Users\nvn\source\repos\market\Market.Core\Market.Core\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 85
```

For some reason, the actual error - the IP address not being found in the GeoIP DB - was being hidden in the stack trace that was being thrown in prod. Not really sure why, but either people with an IP range we didn't have in the free version was being used, or there was some loopback error the same way there is when we debug in dev mode.

Anyway, this is how I handled it -

```
// Determine IP address of request.
                    var ipAddress = HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                    try
                    {
                        // Grab the city if it's not null
                        var city = reader.City(ipAddress);
                        ViewBag.Zip = city.Postal.Code;
                        ViewBag.CurrentDistance = Distance;
                    }
                    catch(AddressNotFoundException e)
                    {

                        logger.Warn(e.ToString());
                        // Grab the city if it's not null
                        var city = reader.City("insert a random IP here");
                        ViewBag.Zip = city.Postal.Code;
                        ViewBag.CurrentDistance = Distance;
                    }
```

Thanks for your help everyone.